# Get rid of HTML tags, characters, numbers and single letter words simultaneously with Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, text, data-cleaning

I have a problem in data cleansing for text analysis. Now I have done four Regex on my data and still unwanted words are there. I wanted to know if there's a way to select just words!
I know that Scikit-learn has this option but I'm not working on English text.
This is what I entered for each of the above but I was wondering if there's another way to do so

```
def clean(data):
    e = re.compile(r"\b[a-zA-Z]\b") #single letters
    data = e.sub('', data)
    r = re.compile(r'<[^<]*?>') # html tags
    data = r.sub('', data)
    p = re.compile(r'[^-\w]') # remove characters like \n
    data = p.sub(' ', data)
    q = re.compile(r'[\d_\.]*') # remove numbers
    return q.sub('', data)
```

Comment: HTML and regex do not suit each other. I recommend that you parse your html as an xml tree using something like python's built-in HTML parser: https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: ^^ But surely you do not want to *remove* text contents such as `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&#x41;`!? (Those are actually not HTML tags.)

Comment: @usr2564301 The OP just wants _words_, andmost human languages don't allow `<` or `>` characters in words (although arguably `&` might be an exception, if you consider, say, `M&Ms` a word). And of course `&#x41`… yeah, that's a much more serious problem with the OP's approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced first and second Regex with some line of code and worked very better.

```
def clean(data):
p = re.compile(r'[^-\w]') # remove characters
data = p.sub(' ', data)
q = re.compile(r'[\d_\.]*') # remove numbers
return q.sub('', data)
for i in text_train:
    for j, t in enumerate(text_train[i]):
        text_train[i][j] = [w for w in clean(t).split() if len(w)>1]
```

the code above tokenized the text and accepts only words with more than one letter.
for the other problem I tried @laurent_laporte answer but I still got `&amp` in my text. Instead added that in stop words file, Not professional but works.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use RegEx for that, you can use the RegEx `r'<[^>]+>'` to match and remove all the tags.

There is also a standard function to convert `&smp;` and other classics entities into characters: `xml.sax.saxutils.unescape`.

Here is a simple demonstration:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
import re

sub_text = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>').sub

html = '<p class="Body">me &amp; you</p>'

text = unescape(sub_text('', html))

print(text)
```

You get: “me & you”

You can then add more rules to filter your data.

The other way is to use [lxml](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) to parse your HTML data and a xpath function to get the text

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fragment_fromstring(html)
text = root.xpath('string()')
```

(Not tested)

Comment: I don't know why nobody understands my question. I know how to omit each of the unwanted words in my question, but I was looking for a solution for all, if there is.

Comment: So, you ought to improve your question: give us an example, what you have, what you expect…